# Error 1064 in version MySQL 8.0 Cannot find the error

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax

```
CREATE DEFINER= `root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `articulos_ricardo_parte1`()
BEGIN
DECLARE num INTEGER;
SELECT identificador INTO @num
FROM articulos
WHERE empleado = 'Ricardo';
CALL articulos_ricardo_parte2 ();
END
```

Cannot understand where is the syntax error. Someone help, please

Comment: You don't appear to have set delimiters..Also (but nor related to your error) you cannot push a result set into a variable so you may need to LIMIT the select. AND user defined variables are not the same or interchangeable with declared variables.

Comment: How I should do that?

Comment: Error 1064 typically comes with an error message, which may contain a hint. Please add it to the question

Comment: Read manual https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/stored-programs-defining.html search tinternet amend code.

Answer (score 0):

You should  to the var without @ and last  add delimiter (eg $$) and add the delimiter at end

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER= `root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `articulos_ricardo_parte1`()
BEGIN
DECLARE num INTEGER;
SELECT identificador INTO num
FROM articulos
WHERE empleado = 'Ricardo';
CALL articulos_ricardo_parte2 ();
END $$
```

Comment: CALL articulos_ricardo_parte2 (); not the same name as the procedure being created - but could be an op typo or wip.

Comment: @Tania Ragozina are you Using PHPMYADMIN? And how are you creating (using a wizard or otherwise). Otherwise this code syntaxes fine for me.